# echo message not coming on terminal with systemd

Tags: linux, console, fedora, tty, systemd

I have systemd service, say xyzWarmup.service.

Here is the service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Xyz agent.
After=fooAfter.service
Before=fooBefore1.service
Before=fooBefore2.service

[Service]
# During boot the xyz.sh script reads input from /dev/console.  If the user
# hits <ESC>, it will skip waiting for xyz and abc to startup.
Type=oneshot
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xyz.sh start

RemainAfterExit=True
ExecStop=/usr/bin/xyz.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Following is the part of xyz.sh.

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                               
#                                                              
### BEGIN INIT INFO                                                                                                                                                                                         
# Required-Stop: Post                                                                                                                                                                                       
### END INIT INFO                                                                                                                                                                                           

XYZ=/usr/bin/Xyz
prog="Xyz"
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog
msg="Completing initialization"

start() {
     # Run wfw in background                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ulimit -c 0
    # wfw has a default timeout of 10 minutes - just pick a large value                                                                                                                                     
    wfw -t 3600 xyz abc >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    PID=$!

    # Display the message here after spawning wfw so Esc can work                                                                                                                                           
    echo -n $"$msg (press ESC to skip): "
    while [ 1 ]; do
        read -s -r -d "" -N 1 -t 0.2 CHAR || true
        if [ "$CHAR" = $'\x1B' ]; then
            kill -9 $PID 2>/dev/null
            # fall through to wait for process to exit                                                                                                                                                      
        fi

        STATE="`ps -p $PID -o state=`"
        if [ "$STATE" = ""  ]; then 
            # has exited                                                                                                                                                                                    
            wait $PID 2>/dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "[ OK ]" 
                echo
                exit 0
            else
                echo "[ FAILED ]"
                echo "This is failure"  
                               exit 1
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```

When this script runs during boot I see the following message coming from the script

```
 Completing initialization (press ESC to skip):
```

Updated:
This is the additional output which I see after the previous line

```
[[  OK  ] Started Xyz agent.\n'
```

If you carefully see, there are 2 opening square brackets( '[' ), from this it looks like that systemd is overwriting the log messages. The first "[" comes from the initscript's "[ OK ]". Can somebody explain this better ?

I don't see "[ OK ]" or "[ FAILED ]" on my screen.

When I was using this script as initscript in Fedora14, I used to see these messages. Once, I have shifted to systemd. I have started seeing this issue.

systemd version is :  systemd-201-2.fc18.9.i686 and systemd.default_standard_output=tty

Kindly help.

Comment: Multi-posted to several Stack Exchanges: http://serverfault.com/questions/743861/

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your issue here is that the script is never getting attached to the TTY. The output is showing up because you have that hard-coded to go to `/dev/console` in your script. With `StandardInput=tty`, systemd waits until the tty is available, and it's probably already in use. Your script is just sitting there not connected to input in the infinite loop. You could try `StandardInput=tty-force`, and I bet that will work, although I'm not sure what *else* that might break.

Personally, I think I might go back and rethink the approach entirely. It sounds like you want the boot to entirely block on this service, but let you skip by hitting escape. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Boot doesn't block, it just wait until the wfw process exits automatically or before that if someone hit ESC( in this case we kill the wfw process )

Comment: and also there are many other intiscripts also which run before and after this script which also DON'T have hard-coded to go to /dev/console but even then all the echo messages comes on the screen. I suspect is something is happening as soon as wfw gets exits or gets killed. I have even tried adding many more echo messages with hard coding it to go to /dev/console and they all appear if above that if statement.

Comment: One more thing note here is I receive echo messages from inside while loop, if they are before if statemnt that I have mentioned. It looks like as if as soon as the wfw exits/gets killed, I am unable to connect to tty

Comment: On removing /dev/console, I do see that message still.

Comment: StandardInput=tty-force or StandardOutput=tty-force also doesn't solves.

Comment: What do you get from `systemctl status xyzWarmup.service`?

Comment: I still _do_ really suggest a different way to do this. If it has to be at-the-console-esc-without-login, rather than using /dev/console, maybe pick a tty which isn't allocated to a getty or other program?

Comment: sudo systemctl status XyzWarmup
XyzWarmup.service - Xyz agent.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/XyzWarmup.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2015-12-18 04:06:57 PST; 2h 1min ago
  Process: 2260 ExecStart=/usr/bin/xyz.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: I am ready to change as you say but I want to know the reason for this first. I want to root cause this issue. One more observation from side, if in system conf file I change systemd.default_standard_output=console. missing messages starts appearing.